# Array Resizing, currently has terminal error

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

So I am currently getting this error saying: 
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)"
I am unsure why I am getting this message. I am assuming it has something to do with either some return values or that some of my strings are set equal to argv. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int* insert(int arr[], int& size, int value, int position)
{
    int *arrb = new int[size+1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < position; i++)
    arrb[i] = arr[i];
    arrb[i] = value;
    size = size+1;
    for(int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
    {
    arrb[j] = arr[j-1];
    }

    delete arr;
    arr = arrb;
    return arr;
}

int* remove(int arr[], int& size, int position)
{
    int *arrb = new int[size-1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < position; i++)
    {
    arrb[i] = arr[i];
    size = size-1;
    }
    for(int j = i; j < size; j++)
    {
    arrb[j] = arr[j+1];
    }

    delete arr;
    arr = arrb;
    return arr;
}

int count(int arr[], int size, int target)
{
    int total = 0 ;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == target)
        {
            total += 1 ;
        }
    }
return total ;
}

void print(int arr[], int size)
{
    cout<< "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<< arr[i];
        if(i < size -1)
        {
        cout<< ", ";
        }
    }
    cout<< "]";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int value = 0;
int position = 0;
int choice = 0;
int numEntries = 0;
int* nums = nullptr;
string fileName = argv[1];
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fileName);
if( inFile.is_open() )
{
inFile >> numEntries;
string sizeS = argv[2];
int size = 0;
size = stoi(sizeS);
nums = new int[numEntries];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        inFile >> nums[i];
    }
    cout<< "Make a selection: \n";
    cout<< "1) Insert\n";
    cout<< "2) Remove\n";
    cout<< "3) Count\n";
    cout<< "4) print\n";
    cout<< "5) Exit\n";
    cout<< "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    do{
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout<< "Enter number to insert: ";
            cin>> value;
            do{
            cout<< "Enter position: ";
            cin>> position;
            insert(nums,size,value,position);
            }while(position < 0 || position > size);
            nums = insert(nums, size, value, position);
        }

        if(choice == 2)
        {
            do{
            cout<< "Insert a position: ";
            cin >> position;
                if (position < 0 || position >= size)
                {
                cout << "Please enter a correct position.\n";
                }
            }while(position < 0 || position >= size);
            nums = remove(nums, size, position);

        }

        if(choice == 3)
        {
            cout<< "Pick a number to count: ";
            int target = 0;
            cin >> target;
            count(nums, size, target);
        }

        if(choice == 4)
        {
            print(nums, size);
        }

    }while(choice != 5);

}else{
    cout<< "\nError";
}
delete nums;
return (0);
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to step through your program with your debugger and find out exactly where this error is being thrown. Need help getting started?

Comment: Did you run with a debugger?  valgrind?  Build with address sanitization enbaled?

Comment: Note that in the case of `remove()`, the new size is `size-1`. You might want to take that into account

Comment: Maybe this is your bug: `string fileName = argv[1];` Your code does not care if there was an argument passed via the command line / shell or not.

Comment: Why not simply use `std::vector<int>`?  What you're trying to do is already done by `std::vector`, without error.

Comment: After using valgrind, I got this information back. possibly lost: 144 bytes in 1 blocks.  ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted (core dumped). These are the main things that came back so it does seem that I do have a small memory leak which may be part of the issue

Comment: You use the wrong form of `delete` throughout your code.  It should be `delete []`, not `delete`.  Second thing is after you've done this assignment, run away from it and use `std::vector`.

Comment: As of the size value, by passing by reference wouldn't that change the size? I saw in other examples people instead returned the size-1 opposed to the array, but in the problem itself I am asked to return the array.

Comment: A pointer by itself has no idea about the "size".  You have to carry around and maintain that `size` variable correctly and consistently.  That's why `size` should be encapsulated in a class -- this is what `std::vector` does, and even if this a home-made code, you should have done the same thing (create a class, and not have to maintain disjointed variables).

Comment: I just realized what I've been doing wrong the whole time. I was forgetting to input my command line arguments when running the program. I appreciated the help though everyone! It's nice to know there is a productive and helpful resource like this website